# create a component which accept the input of time range object and return the array of merged time range object javascript

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

create a component which accept the input of time range object and return the array of merged time range object

Input

```
[
  {"day":2, "sTime":"08:00", "eTime":"09:00"},
  {"day":2, "sTime":"09:00", "eTime":"10:00"},
  {"day":2, "sTime":"09:00", "eTime":"10:00"},
  {"day":2, "sTime":"10:00", "eTime":"11:00"},
  {"day":2, "sTime":"10:30", "eTime":"11:30"},
  {"day":2, "sTime":"10:00", "eTime":"12:00"},
  {"day":2, "sTime":"10:00", "eTime":"11:00"}
]
```

Output

```
[
  { "sTime":"08:00", "eTime":"09:00", "mergedSession": [] },
  { "sTime":"09:00", "eTime":"10:00", "mergedSession": [
    { "day":2, "sTime":"09:00", "eTime":"10:00" },
    { "day":2, "sTime":"09:00", "eTime":"10:00" }
  ]},
  { "sTime":"10:00", "eTime":"12:00", "mergedSession": [
    { "day":2, "sTime":"10:00", "eTime":"11:00" },
    { "day":2, "sTime":"10:30", "eTime":"11:30" },
    { "day":2, "sTime":"10:00", "eTime":"12:00" },
    { "day":2, "sTime":"10:00", "eTime":"11:00" }
  ]}
]
```

Comment: paste properly formatted json in quesions.

Comment: how did you decide the sTime and eTime for the output JSON ?

Comment: We have merge the session which comes in between a range , for example suppose the time is 10:00 to 12:00 then , all the session in between 10:00 and 12:00 must be merged inside the mergedSession

Comment: So you define the ranges separately? Or do they (somehow) follow from the inputs?

Comment: actually sTime is start time and eTime is End time of that perticular session

Answer (score 0):

Here's an attempt that produces your desired result. What it roughly does (comments in the code should explain some more details)

1. Prepare the data for easier comparison (add `Number` values for the times)
2. Go over the data and create sessions
3. If the start of a slot fits in the current session

   - push it to the inner array
   - extend end of session if needed
4. If the start is outside the slot, create a new session and continue
5. Sanitize the output and put it in the correct order

<sub>P.S. Code style is heavily opinionated, let me know if there's stuff that's hard to read...</sub>

```js
// UTILS
// Utility to go from time string to comparable int
const parseTime = str => Number(str.replace(":", ""));

// Translate back to a time strin. E.g.: 800 -> "08:00"
const timeToStr = int => {
  const str = (int + "").padStart(4, "0");
  return [str[0], str[1], ":", str[2], str[3]].join("");
};

// Logic for checking if a slot is in the previous session
const inRange = (min, max, t) => t >= min && t < max;

// MERGE LOGIC
const merge = ([lastMerge, ...merges], { day, sTime, eTime, sVal, eVal }) =>
  // There has to be a "session",
  lastMerge && 
  // The session has to match our current day,
  lastMerge.day === day && 
  // Our start has to be within the range of the session:
  inRange(
    lastMerge.sVal,
    lastMerge.eVal,
    sVal
  ) ? [{ 
        day, 
        sVal: lastMerge.sVal,
        // Extend the session if needed
        eVal: Math.max(eVal, lastMerge.eVal),
        sTime: lastMerge.sTime,
        // Update the original string as well,
        eTime: timeToStr(Math.max(eVal, lastMerge.eVal)),
        // Add the current slot to the session
        mergedSession: [ { day, sTime, eTime, sVal, eVal} ].concat(lastMerge.mergedSession)
       }].concat(merges)
     : // Create a new session 
       [{
         day,
         sVal,
         eVal,
         sTime,
         eTime,
         mergedSession: [  { day, sTime, eTime, sVal, eVal} ]
       }].concat(lastMerge || []).concat(merges);




const input = [
  {"day":2, "sTime":"08:00", "eTime":"09:00"},
  {"day":2, "sTime":"09:00", "eTime":"10:00"},
  {"day":2, "sTime":"09:00", "eTime":"10:00"},
  {"day":2, "sTime":"10:00", "eTime":"11:00"},
  {"day":2, "sTime":"10:30", "eTime":"11:30"},
  {"day":2, "sTime":"10:00", "eTime":"12:00"},
  {"day":2, "sTime":"10:00", "eTime":"11:00"}
];

console.log(
  input
    // Add some numeric "time" values for easier comparisons
    .map(slot => Object.assign({}, slot, { sVal: parseTime(slot.sTime), eVal: parseTime(slot.eTime) }))
    // The actual merge
    .reduce(merge, [])
    // We concatenated the results in reverse; undo that
    .reverse()
    // Remove the temporary int. values used for easier comparisons
    .map(({ day, sTime, eTime, mergedSession }) => 
      // Remove mergedSessions with 1 element
      ({ sTime, eTime, mergedSession: mergedSession.length > 1 
        ? mergedSession.map(({ day, sTime, eTime }) => ({ day, sTime, eTime }))
        : []
      })
    )
)
```

Comment: ty for help but the output dosent match

Comment: i have trrid it several times

Comment: In what way does my output not match the requirement? I cannot see any of your code changes. Please paste the code to your own question or to a jsfiddle/codepen and let me know where I can find it.

Comment: check my answer

Comment: see the output properly, what we need to do is that we need to just merge the sessions, means the session which are starting from 9 to 10 and 10 to 11 will get merged inside the mergedSession of 9 to 12, similarly all sessions is are inside a perticular range must be merged

Comment: sorry mu mistake i just changed some part of code thats why it was showing me some kind of different output

Comment: actually your coding is very high level

Answer (score 0):

var myArray=[{"day":2,"sTime":"08:00","eTime":"09:00"},{"day":2,"sTime":"09:00","eTime":"10:00"},{"day":2,"sTime":"09:00","eTime":"10:00"},{"day":2,"sTime":"10:00","eTime":"11:00"},{"day":2,"sTime":"10:30","eTime":"11:30"},{"day":2,"sTime":"10:00","eTime":"12:00"},{"day":2,"sTime":"10:00","eTime":"11:00"}];

```
var newarr=[];
var output=[];
var scipArray=[];
```

function merge(array){

```
                if(array.length==0)
                {
                        console.log("Array is empty");
                }else{
                    for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
                    var a=array[i]["sTime"].split(":");
                    var b=array[i]["eTime"].split(":");
                    var aminutes=(+a[0]) * 60 + (+a[1]);
                    var bminutes = (+b[0]) * 60 + (+b[1]);

                    calculateMerge(array,aminutes,bminutes);

                        if(scipArray.includes(i)==true)
                        {
                            //continue;
                        }else{
                    var mergeArray={"sTime":array[i]["sTime"],"eTime":array[i]["eTime"],"mergeSession":newarr};
                    output=output.push(mergeArray);
                        }

                    }console.log(output);
                }
```

}

function calculateMerge(array,aminutes,bminutes){

```
        for(var j = 0; j < array.length; j++){

            var c=array[j]["sTime"].split(":");
            var d=array[j]["eTime"].split(":");
            var cminutes=(+c[0]) * 60 + (+c[1]);
            var dminutes = (+d[0]) * 60 + (+d[1]);

            if(aminutes<=cminutes && bminutes>=dminutes){
                newarr.push(array[j]);
                scipArray.push(j);
            }
            else{
                newarr;
            }
        }
```

}

merge(myArray);